# Hot to implement wcf client with ws-security with timestamp, username, encrypt and signature?

Tags: wcf-client, ws-security

I try to write wcf client of java server with WS-Security specifications. Is there any way to implement the client programatically in C# with the order I give at the question (timestamp, username, encrypt and signature)

Comment: What Soap versión the service use? If Soap 1.1 then you have to go CustomBinding if 1.2 you can go with WsHttpBinding . BTW, why code and not config?

Comment: I should use Soap 1.1. In fact, I don't know how to configure or code. If possible, can you give an example by configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Well is hard to tell by your post what will be your corresponding setup. Here you have the config I use to consume a java web service that use ws-security. In my case i was provided with a client certificate and for the service i exported and install the certificate from the service's site.
For the several gotchas you for sure will have, refer to [this site](http://webservices20.blogspot.com/2012/06/12-common-wcf-interop-confusions.html) 
In the following replace xx with your the certificates Thumbprint. 
Let us know your progress.

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>

      <customBinding>

 <binding name="MyBindingName" >          
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11"/>
          <security authenticationMode="MutualCertificate" enableUnsecuredResponse="true" allowSerializedSigningTokenOnReply="true"
                    messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10"
                    includeTimestamp="true">
          </security>
          <httpsTransport />
        </binding>        
      </customBinding>


    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ClientCertificateBehavior">
          <clientCredentials>
            <clientCertificate findValue="xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx"
                               storeLocation="CurrentUser" storeName="My" 
                               x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" />

            <serviceCertificate>
              <defaultCertificate findValue="xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx" 
                                  storeLocation="CurrentUser" storeName="My"
                                  x509FindType="FindByThumbprint"/>
              <authentication  />
            </serviceCertificate> 
          </clientCredentials>

        </behavior>

      </endpointBehaviors>

    </behaviors>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://YOURSERVICE_ADDRESS"
        binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyBindingName"
        contract="srvContract" name="srvContract"  behaviorConfiguration="ClientCertificateBehavior">
      </endpoint>

    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```